# Camel SFTP Endpoint not Uploading File

Tags: java, apache-camel, sftp

I am trying to use the camel-ftp endpoint (specifically the sftp module) to upload a newly produced CSV file.

The relevant portion of my route is as follows:

```
...
<marshal>
    <csv></csv>
</marshal>
<to uri="file:incoming?tempPrefix=.&amp;fileName=feed.csv" />
<to uri="sftp://username@linuxserver/home/username/file.csv?password=password" />
...
```

Note: the "file" at

> incoming/feed.csv

is created successfully, camel's last few lines of output read:

```
[DefaultQuartzScheduler-camel_Worker-1] INFO org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations - JSCH -> Authentication succeeded (password). 
[DefaultQuartzScheduler-camel_Worker-1] INFO org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations - Connected to sftp://username@linuxserver:22 
[DefaultQuartzScheduler-camel_Worker-1] INFO org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.RemoteFileProducer - Connected and logged in to: Endpoint[sftp://username@linuxserver/home/username/file.csv?password=xxxxxx]
```

But there is no

> /home/username/file.csv

on linuxserver.

Note:

I have the same results when I configure my sftp rout as either of the following:

```
<to uri="sftp://username@linuxserver/home/username/?password=password" />
```

or

```
<to uri="sftp://username@linuxserver/home/username?password=password" />
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Try without the <to file> first so it goes straight to your FTP server.

Comment: Thanks. I just tried this with the same outcome.

Comment: Set DEBUG/TRACE logging and see what is being logged at that level.

Comment: The last line is still "[DefaultQuartzScheduler-camel_Worker-1] INFO org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.RemoteFileProducer - Connected and logged in to: Endpoint[sftp://username@linuxserver/home/username/file.csv?password=xxxxxx]"

Comment: check the logs on the ftp server side, what it says. Also you can enable logging on SFTP library as well (jcraft)

Answer (score 2):

When the directory part of the URI is present, like in:
`<to uri="sftp://username@linuxserver/home/username/?password=password" />`
a file is placed in a directory relative to user home dir (~username/home/username in this case) - so when you want to place a file in the user home dir directly do not specify directory at all - use:
`<to uri="sftp://username@linuxserver?password=password" />`
When you want to place a file outside the home directory use double slash to separate hostname from directory:
`<to uri="sftp://username@linuxserver//home/username/?password=password" />`
Checked using camel 2.10.7. Set trace for logger org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations to verify behaviour.

@Olivier.Roger - ftps != sftp

Answer (score 0):

The sftp endpoint should be specified as

```
ftps://[username@]hostname[:port]/directoryname[?options]
```

So the filename should ne be specified in the URI.
You can choose a filename using the `CamelFileName` header.

You can find additonal information in the [FTP Component documentation](http://camel.apache.org/ftp2.html).

Comment: That was my previous configuration, and I got the same result.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion. I updated my question to reflect this.